# How to use "react native map" for local JPG file like 'Floor Plan'

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, native

I was trying to use "react native map" for one of my project but failed to load local image (JPG or PNG of floor plan) to my app.

I have tried couple of ways using "UrlTile" and "LocalTile", but none seems to work for me. Would be helpful if anyone could help. Thanks

render() {

```
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_DEFAULT} // remove if not using Google Maps
      mapType={MAP_TYPES.STANDARD}
      style={styles.map}
      region={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
      }}
    >
       <LocalTile
         pathTemplate="/storage/floorplan/level1.png"
         tileSize={256}
         zIndex={-1}
       />

    </MapView>
  </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: Try `pathTemplate= require("/storage/floorplan/level1.png")`

Comment: Sorry.. `pathTemplate= require("./storage/floorplan/level1.png")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried both way but still not getting any Image to load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a tiled map and store them in folders like this:
z/x/y.png
You can try this with MapTiler for example. It cuts you an image in pieces and stores it in folders like this.